# Change the display products for phone in 1 column

Tags: wordpress, mobile, woocommerce

My site adapted for phone, but show products in 2 column.
Can I change the display for phone in 1 column?
here's [working website](https://strannik-book.com.ua/category/yoga/)
here's [my test website](http://classica.esy.es/katalog/)
site working on WordPress and WooCommerce
May be someone knows how this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a little css to adjust the width of the product li element. Something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    ul.products li.product {
        width: 96%;
    }
}
```

That would make it one column for any screen less than 1024 pixels wide. You could adjust that number to only affect only smaller screen sizes if desired.

Comment: In what file I need add this code? 
I tried add this in child-themes - style.css but nothing not changed

Comment: It working! I add in custom.css It working!
Sorry, I not understand at the beginning. It's something with cache. On my phone still 2 column, but I tried on another phone, and there 1 column.
Thank you!